# API Gateway - Get StatusCode

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

This should have been such a simple issue and I don't understand why it hasn't come up through all my searching (maybe it's just been a long day).

I have an API Gateway API setup, and I am adding a `Body Mapping Template` to my `Integration Response` for a 400* error group: see image -

[image]

All I would like to get is the StatusCode of the current response (as this is a 400* group - e.g. 401 / 403 / 404 etc.)

The closest I came was through this site: [AWS help documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) and I thought I would be able to use something like `$context.statusCode` - but no luck.

Am I going crazy, or is this just not something required often?

PS - Making changes to any Lambda functions being called, is not an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no mapping template variable in API Gateway dedicated to the integration response status code.

We will certainly add this as a feature request.

At current time you are limited to hardcoding the status code value in your response templates. You would either need to define generic status codes (i.e "4XX") or define integration responses for every status code you want to capture. While this seems tedious, this could be managed relatively easily in a Swagger template.

At current time the only way to see the integration response status code is via CloudWatch Logs.

Thanks,
Ryan / Amazon API Gateway

Comment: Well, that wasn't the answer I was expecting... I don't understand why all the functionality to allow regex status codes is allowed but then you cant catch what statusCode it is. Regardless, thanks for the feedback, lets hope this is implemented sooner, rather than later.

Comment: I agree. with @Hexie. At the very least, I wish I could see the Integration Response status code in the Cloudwatch log, but I don't even see that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending error codes from your server then you can easily map them.

I have done something similar but I have used different trick to do. I used to send my own error entities and codes from server.

You have to map those error entities and error codes coming from server to the response that comes from amazon servers. I will try and explain what I mean by this. Api Gateway doesn't send response coming from your own server to the client automatically. You have to map those responses. For example, map 200 as a SUCESS and response entity will be default, that is whatever coming from server.

Now, we default success response is managed but what about error codes and error entities. You have to map them manually.

There are two ways you can do this,

One is manual, go to your api. Create error entities or models. Map them manually for each response code.

This one uses swaggger, 
Solution is to import swagger specification of error entities. Add response templates to the swagger specification and let amazon do their job.

I can help you more with swagger. It depends how you are setting up your api on amazon.

Visit this for amazon extenstions to swagger,
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html#api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-response

Comment: Thanks Ajinkya but as I mentioned,I don't want to effect any lambda functions and server calls, this is assuming the status is unknown. I'm assuming there must be a way, through headers or something to get the same response. If fiddle or postman can do it, then surely this isn't difficult and it's possibly just a property I've missed

Comment: P.S. I'd also like to avoid setting a different response for each known status type, that'll be ridiculous on big APIs